# Getting Page to render properly in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer

I am just wondering what the percentage of users still use IE7 to view the web? I have a webpage that renders just fine in Firefox, IE8 & 9, and Google Chrome, but when it comes to any IE version 7 or less, it's complete garbage. Would it be worth getting the page to view properly in IE7 or should I just stick with viewing in IE8 and above?

The site is a lawn care company just fyi.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do a Google search on IE7 market share.  You'll discover a lot of different answers.

Comment: What does said complete garbage look like? It should be serviceable in any browser, for sure, but you don’t have to make the "IE7 version" fancy.

Comment: "complete garbage" meaning links and info is still there, just really off in positioning...way off!

Comment: @Johny: If it’s way off, just spend the extra time to make them look acceptable, even if it’s a bit of an ugly hack.

Comment: I ll work on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.81% of global internet users are using IE7 as a browser, per [w3counter.com](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php). It's small, but still a fair amount. It just may be worth optimizing your site for IE7.

If your site is still functional, (it seems so from your last comment), even if it's not that aesthetically nice, it may just not be worth the trouble. It's for you to decide.

Remember that you can find a lot of data about Internet Explorer 7 percentages if you do a [simple search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ie7%20percentage%20users).

**Edit:** Upon further research, it appears that although w3counter says that IE7's market share is about 5 percent, other counters like [statcounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201112-201212-bar) actually place it at around 1 percent.

Comment: Answer most accurately answered my question.

Comment: Upon further research, it appears that although w3counter says that IE7's market share is about 5 percent, other counters like http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201112-201212-bar actually place it at around 1 percent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want people to visit your website while at work, I'd recommend taking IE7 into consideration. Large corporations, due to license and maintenance expenses, stick with IE versions for many years. IE6 is almost extinct now but IE7 is still around. You can google to find stats regarding browser usage in your country.

Comment: I ve done a google search on IE7 market share as Brian suggested above, and I am finding the IE7 usage globally, including here in US, to be less than 5% of total users. Not too encouraging to continue supporting IE7.