# Layouting slider in IE7 with animation and absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a slider in my web application that is absolutely positioned and contains a content div, which is also absolutely positioned by top: 30px and left, right and bottom to be 5px.

Here is a fiddle of this:
http://jsfiddle.net/MHNs7/
The source is also appended [1].

The slider has a red background, the enclosed content div is blue.

In most browsers, it works fine, but in IE7, the content divs height is to great - there is no red "border" on the bottom of the slider.

This does not happen when the slider is not animated - if all JavaScript is removed and the slider is initially visible, everything works out:
http://jsfiddle.net/TkZ4f/2/
The source is also appended [2].

The problem is also fixed, if some sort of "re-layout" of the browser window is triggered, but I could not get a good idea on when or why this "re-layout" happens. It occurs for example, if I open the IE developer toolbar.

Any hints what happens here, and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Jost

Source for the first fiddle (With animation and bug):

HTML [1]:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <button id="toggle">toggle</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <button id="contentchange">change content</button>
    <div id="content">
      <span>Content</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS [1]:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  var slider = jQuery('#slider');

  slider.hide();

  jQuery('#toggle').click(function() {
    var slider = jQuery('#slider');

    if (slider.is(':visible'))  {

      slider.stop().animate({
        'height': '0',
        'opacity': '0'
      }, function() {
        slider.hide();
      });
    }
    else {

      slider.show();
      slider.stop().animate({
        'height': '200px',
        'opacity': '1'
      });
    }
  });

  jQuery('#contentchange').click(function() {
    var content = jQuery('#content span');

    content.text(Math.random().toString(2).substring(10));
  });
});
```

CSS [1]:

```
#slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;

  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;

  padding: 10px;

  top: 40px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;

  background: blue;
}
```

Source for the second fiddle (Without animation):

HTML [2]:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <button id="toggle">toggle</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <button id="contentchange">change content</button>
    <div id="content">
      <span>Content</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No JS [2].

CSS [2]:

```
#slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;

  padding: 10px;

  top: 40px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;

  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to drop support for older, hassle-browsers like IE7? It's market share is currently at 1.5% (as a May, I believe this is global).

Comment: It is in the contract... If I'd have to decide, IE7 users would get a big warning sign.

Comment: yeah, well look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047617/getting-page-to-render-properly-in-ie7/14047662#14047662

Comment: It's really hard to fix older browser's problems, because your code complies with the specs and stuff... so isn't kind of like you have to patch the browser's bug, which is ridiculous... it's hard for me to find work-arounds for this kind of stuff.